# How do I update my collection in mongoDB so i add an userId

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, key-value

My actually collection looks like this

```
    ID: ...,
   param1: value1
   param2: value2
```

But i want to add a user id to this object so that this will be look like this

```
userid:{
ID: ...,
param1: value1,
param2: value2
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a new schema name user_detail
now u have 2 schema one is user and other is user_detail
user schema will be like
schema:{
userid:{
type:Object,
ref:user_detail
}
}

user_detail schema:{
ID: ...,
param1: value1,
param2: value2
}
By doing this your end result will be like this

_Id:'',
userid:{
_Id:'',
param1: value1,
param2: value2
}